# java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

`[2013-09-05 20:53:17 - Emulator]` Error accepting connection, aborting
`[2013-09-05 20:53:17 - AndroidSleepMachine]` Failed to install `AndroidSleepMachine.apk` on device `'emulator-5554'`: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
`[2013-09-05 20:53:17 - AndroidSleepMachine] java.io.IOException`: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

```
[2013-09-05 20:53:17 - AndroidSleepMachine] Launch canceled!
```

Thats the errors I am getting in Eclipse whenever I try to run my application on the emulator. I have tried Every fix I have found on the internet.  I have restarted eclipse, I have restarted the adb, I have made a new adb, I have used the command line to kill the adb and restart the adb, reinstalled all of eclipse and all the sdks...I have tried everything and I do not know what else to do...PLEASE HELP